# `sudo su` doesn't ask for password

Tags: sudo, etc

I typed `sudo su` in the terminal, and it changed to root without asking for a password. I also tried typing `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it didn't ask for a password either. When I installed Unity (1 hr ago) it asked for a password with the usual `[sudo] password for proc-daemon:` .

In case it is my `/etc/sudoers`, I have posted it here (without comments):

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

As you can see, nowhere is there `proc-daemon ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`.

Why is this happening?

I have XUbuntu 15.10 with Unity.

## EDIT:

As requested in a comment, `sudo -l` outputted:

```
Matching Defaults entries for proc-daemon on Exitron2000:
env_reset, mail_badpass,
secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:        /sbin\:/bin

User proc-daemon may run the following commands on Exitron2000:
(ALL : ALL) ALL
```

For some reason, `sudo -l` did ask for a password.

## EDIT 2:

`sudo -k` made it go back to normal.

Comment: BTW: proc-daemon is my username and I am an admin.

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `sudo -l`.

Comment: What is `sudo -l`?

Comment: `sudo -l` displays what sudo privileges you currently have. Try running `sudo -k` and then `sudo -l`.

Comment: `sudo -k` did nothing and `sudo -l` did the same thing as before.

Comment: `sudo -k` does nothing visible. It resets your [sudo timeout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout).

Comment: Thank you. When I did `sudo -k` and then `sudo su`, it asked for my password. How to I mark this as answered?